# Python Binance request blocked by internet provider

Tags: python, python-requests, binance

Currently, i am working to automate my binance account using `python-binance 1.0.0++`

Unfortunately, the web is blocked by the government but I still can access the web using public DNS (google / cloudflare) by setup the security settings. Or i can also add the DNS to my Network Adapter

But when I try the `python-binance` to `get_all_orders`, then the result still shows a scraped blocked landing page by our government even when i do browsing using the chrome / edge, no issue at all. I have tried to change the DNS at the browser and at Network Adapter. Nothing are work for me. The error is shown below.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/ping (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Anyone can help me to do the same on my python as my browser work?
[image]

Comment: Does this solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror

Comment: Yes, in python-binance have the properties to set verified to false. But the result is scraped blocked landing page

Comment: From looking at the certificate, running `pip install certifi` should work. Have you already tried that?

Comment: Yes, after i try to `pip install certifi`, the package was installed.

Comment: I added the image of difference when i do a ping to the binance and when I browse via web