# Python get request: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, http, get

I'm trying a simple Python get request but failing. As described [here](https://datagy.io/python-requests-headers/), I should be able to:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
print(response.headers)
```

But instead I get

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)
```

I'm running a script from a Windows command prompt. Is it perhaps because I'm behind a company firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest fix is setting `verify=False`:

```
response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', verify=False)
```

Posibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/12864892/8473136