# How to read a specific table from a given url?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to python and trying to download the countries GDP per capita data. I am trying to read the data from this website: https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/by-gdp

I tried to read the data but, I found no tables found error.
I can see the data is in `r.text` but somehow pandas can not read that table.
How to solve the problem and read the data?

## MWE

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/by-gdp"

r = requests.get(url)
raw_html = r.text  # I can see the data is here, but pd.read_html says no tables found
df_list = pd.read_html(raw_html)
print(len(df_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is embedded via `<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">` and rendered by browser only, so you have to adjust your script a bit:

```
pd.json_normalize(
    json.loads(
        BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(url).text
        ).select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text)['props']['pageProps']['data']
)
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/by-gdp"


df = pd.json_normalize(
    json.loads(
        BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(url).text
        ).select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text)['props']['pageProps']['data']
)
df[['continent', 'country', 'pop','imfGDP', 'unGDP', 'gdpPerCapita']]
```

##### Output

|  | continent | country | pop | imfGDP | unGDP | gdpPerCapita |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | North America | United States | 338290 | 2.08938e+13 | 18624475000000 | 61762.9 |
| 1 | Asia | China | 1.42589e+06 | 1.48626e+13 | 11218281029298 | 10423.4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 210 | Asia | Syria | 22125.2 | 0 | 22163075121 | 1001.71 |
| 211 | North America | Turks and Caicos Islands | 45.703 | 0 | 917550492 | 20076.4 |

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I can't directly read the page due to `SSLCertVerificationError`. to circumvent that, I have downloaded the whole webpage locally and trying to read the data from that. I have a local HTML: `GDP Ranked by Country 2022.html` along with associated folder. How can I read from the local HTML file?

Comment: Have not run into such error - So this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus May 
 read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror or use `BeautifulSoup(open('MY FILE PATH AND FILE ','r').read())`

Comment: `open file` method worked fine. Thanks a lot. If you are from Texas stay safe, weather is very bad here. Have a great day!