# SSL Certificate Error on VS Code while downloading Torchvision dataset

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

I was trying to import the CIFAR10 dataset in VS Code. However, an error pops up when trying to run the code. Please find below the attached code and output.

```
from torchvision import datasets
data_path= 'dataset_cifar/'
cifar10=datasets.CIFAR10(data_path,train=True,download=True)
cifar10_val=datasets.CIFAR10(data_path,train=False,download=True)
```

I get the following error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1345             try:
-> 1346                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1347                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1284         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1285         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1286 

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1330             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1331         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1332 

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1279             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1280         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1281 

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1039         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1040         self.send(msg)
...
-> 1349                 raise URLError(err)
   1350             r = h.getresponse()
   1351         except:

URLError:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your code to "workaround" the certification like

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: it does not seem to work when i am using pycharm terminal, any other alternatives?