# Issue with Python Requests Library: Getting SSL Certificate Verify Failed Error

Tags: python, ssl, https, request

I'm currently working on a Python script that utilizes the requests library to make API requests. However, I'm facing an issue where I consistently get an "SSL certificate verify failed" error. I've tried searching for solutions online, but none of the suggested fixes seem to work.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/api'
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

And here's the error message I'm encountering:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api (Caused by SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))

I've already tried upgrading the certifi library, setting the verify parameter to False (which I know is not a recommended solution), and checking the system time. Despite these efforts, the issue persists.

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this SSL certificate verification error and suggest a reliable solution? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

Comment: *"setting  the verify parameter to False"* - do you really get exactly the same error in this case? I would expect that it either works or that you get a different error, because this disables certificate validation which means it should no longer break due to a failing validation. If you really get the same error please show the exact code you are using in this case. Also, it can be helpful to provide the URL to find out if this is a server side problem or client side or some middlebox in between

Answer (score 0):

requests module's `verify=True` uses its own CA set that might not have CA that signed your server certificate.

You need to find the location of your system's CA file

And then add that as your verify argument parameter.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/api'
response = requests.get(url, verify="pathToCAFile")

print(response.text)
```

Alternatively, if you just want to fix the warning without fixing the underlying issue, you can disable it using the urllib module:

```py
import requests
import urllib3
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

res = requests.get('https://example.com',verify=False)
```